# Replacing root filesystem with EC2 snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bash, ubuntu-16.04, snapshot

This documentation describes "[Restoring an Amazon EBS Volume from a Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html)".

Having done that this documentation explains "[Making an Amazon EBS Volume Available for Use on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html)"

What I'd now like to know is how to make the restored snapshot the root volume so that when the next reboot occurs the reboot is based on the contents of the restored snapshot.

Can someone explain please ?

Comment: Look at what the device name is of the currently attached root volume, then shutdown and detach it and attach the restored EBS volume with the same device name. That’s it. Boot the instance and go.

Comment: @glaucon did you get your question answered? If yes please accept one of the answers to reward the responders for the time they spent answering you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, you have to detach the existing root volume and attach the one restored from snapshot.

1. *Stop* the instance (don't *terminate* it).
2. In the *EC2 details* look for the *Root volume* name, it will probably be either `/dev/xvda` or `/dev/sda1`. Note it down. Then click on the volume id in the pop-up box when you hover over the Root volume name, e.g. `vol-1234abcd1234abcd`
3. In the *Volumes* screen find the current root volume `vol-1234abcd1234abcd` and from the menu select *Detach volume*.
4. In the *Snapshots* screen select the snapshot you want to restore and in the *Actions* menu click *Create volume*. It will give you the volume id (e.g. `vol-9876efgh9876efgh`). Wait for it to complete.
5. Find your restored snapshot volume in the *Volumes* screen (`vol-9876efgh9876efgh`) and in *Actions* click *Attach volume*.
6. In the dialog select the instance from the menu.
7. The *Root volume* won't be in the menu. Simply write what you noted down in step 1 above, e.g. `/dev/xvda` or `/dev/sda1`.
8. *Start* the instance.

Done :)

Comment: This is excellent , thank you very much and I'm sorry it's taken so long for me to respond.