# Site hosted on EC2 / Amazon held hostage with private key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress, private-key

I have a new client whose previous developer has left her high & dry with her site on Amazon/EC2. He holds the private key to the instance, and though she has full access to the Amazon control panel (she's paying $300/mo for a site that has like 3 visitors per week) she doesn't have any way to get her content off and move to a new host.

I'm not familiar with AWS and am not sure how to help her. The site's group/file permissions are screwed up on the server so exporting the content/database via her WordPress control panel isn't working.

Any ideas on how to help her? Thanks!

Comment: One option: stop the instance, mount the EBS volume (disk) to a new EC2 instance (VM), then copy / export the data as required. You can then re-attach the EBS volume to the original instance and start it to get the site back up.

Comment: You can also make an AMI from the instance and launch it with a new key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two options:

1. **Create an Image** (AMI, snapshot) of the EC2 instance and create a new instance from that Image.

   - It should set the SSH key to the one you specify, i.e. your new one.
   - Make sure that all the Network and Security settings are the same as on the old instance.
   - You may need to re-assign the *Elastic IP* from from the old webserver instance 
     to the new one, or update DNS to point to the new IP.
2. Alternatively **modify the root volume** from a separate EC2 instance.

   1. Start a new EC2 instance with a SSH key you know.
   2. *Stop* the webserver instance (don't *terminate* it).
   3. In the *EC2 details* look for the *Root volume* name, it will probably be either `/dev/xvda` or `/dev/sda1`. Note it down. Then click on the volume id in the pop-up box when you hover over the Root volume name, e.g. `vol-1234abcd1234abcd`
   4. In the *Volumes* screen find the current root volume `vol-1234abcd1234abcd` and from the menu select *Detach volume*.

      - Make a *Snapshot* of the volume, just in case.
   5. Now *Attach* the same volume to the new EC2 instance that you've got access to.
   6. *SSH* to the new instance and `sudo su -` to get `root` privileges.
   7. *Mount* the webserver volume, it will probably be `/dev/sdf1` or `/dev/xvdb1` - check `dmesg | tail -n10` to get a hint of what the disk name is.

      ```
      [root@ip-... ~] # mount /dev/xvdb1 /mnt
      ```
   8. Copy the contents of `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/mnt/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` - make sure the file permissions and ownership are still the same as they were!

      ```
      [root@ip... #] cat /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys > /mnt/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
      ```

      - At the same time you may want to *copy out* the contents of your *WordPress website* and the *database files* (if the DB is on the same instance).
   9. `umount /mnt` from the shell and then *Detach* the volume from the AWS Console.
   10. Now *Attach* it back as the *Root volume* to the old webserver instance.

       - Note that the *Root volume* name won't be in the menu! Simply write what you noted down in step 1 above, e.g. `/dev/xvda` or `/dev/sda1`.
   11. *Start* the instance.

If it goes wrong here is how to [restore the root filesystem from a snapshot](https://serverfault.com/questions/930498/replacing-root-filesystem-with-ec2-snapshot/930653#930653) taken in the step 4 above.

That should do. Hope that helps :)